# Have to copy twice to correctly copy Chinese characters

Tags: windows-7, copy-paste, character-encoding

I'm using Windows 7, I can view Chinese characters fine on webpages, but when I copy and paste them somewhere, they show up as `???`'s. This is probably because I don't have Eastern Asian languages properly set up on my computer.

However, the strange thing is, if I copy twice (e.g. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice consecutively), then the characters will show up properly. So my question is, why do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> × 2 put different data in the clipboard?

I hope I have described the scenario adequately. It's been puzzling me for a while, and I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain this!

Comment: The first step would be to install the language pack in question and see if you have the problem still.

Comment: Oh I'm not too worried about the problem, I'm more curious about why copying+pasting a second time makes a difference.